# jquery image and video slider not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I'm trying to use this slider https://github.com/iprodev/iView. I couldn't see any documentation but I think I'm on the right way.

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xibalbian/yevj7/

HTML:

```
 <div id="iview">

 <!-- Slide 1 -->
 <div data-iview:image="images/big-3.jpg" data-iview:transition="zigzag-top,top-curtain,fade">
 <!-- Video iFrame -->
 <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/nbP4y7hml98?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
 </div>

 <!-- Slide 2 -->
 <div data-iview:image="images/big-3.jpg" data-iview:transition="zigzag-top,top-curtain,fade">
 <!-- Video iFrame -->
 <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/tqIzoIoHQd0?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
 </div>

 </div>
```

The fiddle has all dependencies (js) and I've put all the css files right there.

This is my script to call iview;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#slider').iView();
});
```

Any advice would be appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: you should not use script files from github... it will fail to load

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2SkTW/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny any thoughts about what's wrong?

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2SkTW/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Arun P Johny provided the solution I wanted to answer and close this one,

Here is the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2SkTW/4/

HTML:

```
<div id="iview290">
<!-- Slide 1 -->
<div data-iview:image="images/big-3.jpg" data-iview:transition="zigzag-top,top-curtain,fade">
    <!-- Video iFrame -->
    <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/nbP4y7hml98?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<!-- Slide 2 -->
<div data-iview:image="images/big-3.jpg" data-iview:transition="zigzag-top,top-curtain,fade">
    <!-- Video iFrame -->
    <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/tqIzoIoHQd0?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#iview290 {
display: block;
width:900px !important;
/* Make sure your images are the same size */
height:400px !important;
/* Make sure your images are the same size */
background: #000;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
padding: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
position: relative;
/*-webkit-box-shadow: 0 38px 30px -18px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);

-moz-box-shadow: 0 38px 30px -18px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);

box-shadow: 0 38px 30px -18px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);*/
margin: 40px auto;
}

#iview290 .iviewSlider {
display: block;
width:900px;
/* Make sure your images are the same size */
height:400px;
/* Make sure your images are the same size */
overflow: hidden;
border-radius: 4px;
}

#iview290 .iview-caption {
background: #000000;
}

#iview290 .sl-iview-heading {
font-size:18px !important;
color:#FFFFFF !important;
}

#iview290 .sl-iview-description {
font-size:12px !important;
color:#FFFFFF !important;
}

#iview290 #iview-tooltip {
display: none;
position: absolute;
width: 124px;
height: 100px;
bottom: 30px;
left: -67px;
padding: 10px;
z-index: 100;
}

#iview290 #iview-tooltip div.holder {
display: block;
width: 124px;
height: 84px;
overflow: hidden;
border-radius: 2px;
}

#iview290 #iview-tooltip div.holder div.container {
display: block;
width: 4000px;
}

#iview290 #iview-tooltip div.holder div.container div {
float: left;
display: block;
overflow: hidden;
width: 124px;
height: 84px;
left: -50%;
text-align: center;
}

#iview290 #iview-tooltip div.holder div.container div img {
height: 84px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

jQuery('#iview290').iView({

});

});
```